# Metadata query slow on one specific database

Tags: sql-server, performance, metadata, system-tables

I have quite a weird problem (who doesn't).
Our ETL Software scans source databases to claim object data. It extracts information from INFORMATION_SCHEMA about objects (tables and views)

```
SELECT
t.[TABLE_SCHEMA],
t.[TABLE_NAME],
c.[COLUMN_NAME],
c.[DATA_TYPE],
c.[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH],
c.[NUMERIC_PRECISION],
c.[NUMERIC_SCALE],
c.[DATETIME_PRECISION],
c.[ORDINAL_POSITION],
c.[IS_NULLABLE],
prim.[CONSTRAINT_NAME] AS [PRIMARY_KEY_NAME],
t.[TABLE_TYPE]
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] t
INNER JOIN [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] c
ON t.[TABLE_CATALOG] = c.[TABLE_CATALOG]
AND t.[TABLE_SCHEMA] = c.[TABLE_SCHEMA]
AND t.[TABLE_NAME] = c.[TABLE_NAME]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT tc.[CONSTRAINT_NAME], tc.[CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA], tc.[CONSTRAINT_CATALOG], cc.[TABLE_NAME], cc.[COLUMN_NAME]
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLE_CONSTRAINTS] tc
INNER JOIN [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE] cc
ON tc.[CONSTRAINT_NAME] = cc.[CONSTRAINT_NAME]
AND tc.[CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA] = cc.[CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA]
AND tc.[CONSTRAINT_CATALOG] = cc.[CONSTRAINT_CATALOG]
AND tc.[TABLE_NAME] = cc.[TABLE_NAME]
AND tc.[TABLE_CATALOG] = cc.[TABLE_CATALOG]
AND tc.[TABLE_SCHEMA] = cc.[TABLE_SCHEMA]
WHERE tc.[CONSTRAINT_TYPE] = 'PRIMARY KEY') prim
ON t.[TABLE_CATALOG] = prim.[CONSTRAINT_CATALOG]
AND t.[TABLE_SCHEMA] = prim.[CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA]
AND t.[TABLE_NAME] = prim.[TABLE_NAME]
AND c.[COLUMN_NAME] = prim.[COLUMN_NAME]
ORDER BY t.[TABLE_SCHEMA], t.[TABLE_NAME], c.[ORDINAL_POSITION]
```

For most databases (depending on the amount of objects and columns) this takes one minute to complete. For one specific database this takes between 10 and 35 minutes! I can't seem to figure out why. I cannot changes the above query (since it's embedded in the software) so i'm looking for a way to improve performance on this one database

The query outputs about the same amount of records. I've checked database configuration and those are exactly the same. When i tested with 'SET STATISTICS IO ON' it was clear that there was a lot going on in the less-performing database than there was in the other databases. I've put it in [www.statisticsparser.com](https://statisticsparser.com/) and this is what it looks like for the less-performing:
[image: statistics parsed bad database]
For comparison this is what is looks like for a normal database:
[image: statistics parsed good database]

Myself, i'm out of option. I've tried purging proc and system cache (with corresponding DBCC) and updating statistics on the whole database but it (as expected) did no good.

Any help is appreciated!

Kind regards

EDIT: I've added the query plans to compare with a database with about the same size and structure on the same server (which doesn't have the performance problem: https://file.io/ODajcfrzvGTP

It contains 2 files:
_fast is from the database *without* any problems
_slow is from the database *with* problems

Comment: I'm not sure this is a time **to complete** maybe it's time to get the result on the client, just execute it from SSMS as select ... into #t from... this will esclude getting to the client or just use set statistics time on and look at that time

Comment: You still have options to try. Even if you cannot change the query, you can try reducing it to see which part is causing problems. Remove ORDER BY and see, if it is still slow. Remove one table and see how the runtime changes and so on. Finally you can check the execution plan. Even if these are system tables, the principles are the same. Finally if you want more substantial help you should add the ACTUAL execution plan to your question.

Comment: @sepupic Interesting suggestion. Just tried and problem is still showing the same problem unfortunately...

Comment: @rois i actual know what the problem is. The subquery that finds all constraints and column constraints. When this is left out, the query runs in seconds. 
What i don't understand is, what could by in the system base tables that is not in another database. If you look at the statistics IO of the query it hits some tables way more as opposed to the beter performing database. I'm looking for a hint in that direction.

Comment: Please add actual execution plan as was suggested. How many database schemas do you have?

Comment: Try [updating system table statistics](https://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-system-table-statistics-update/).

Comment: @sepupic i've added 2 sqlplan files. Hopefully they give insight in my problem.

Comment: Your sysschobj statistics in bad plan are very old, it estimates 9 rows where there are 287.309 rows, you should update these statistics as Dan Guzman said

Comment: @DanGuzman thnx. it actually helped decreasing the runtime of the query!

Comment: @sepupic thnx for the insights. after updating the statistics it still runs in like 8 minutes (instead of 30) but i can go on and troubleshoot further myself

Comment: @LonelyDBA92 When I asked you for the number of schemas, it might be you have too many of them, I saw one case when with Windows group users everyone created his own schema so that they were really many but if your tool should only work with dbo it may have sense to give it SELECT only on schema dbo, this way it will query only for objects in dbo schema. Your number of objects in that db is really high that is why I asked about other schemas

Comment: @seupic There are many schemas so i can relate to the query being slow. But then again, the other database i'm testing the is not that different. For example bad database hold 48 schemas, 27 tables and 6489 views (to linked servers). The good database holds 41 schemas, 10 tables and 6260 views (same idea). I would expect the duration of a query to be somewhat the same....

The user that executes the query already has limited read rights (2 schemas) but i don't think that matters in metadata tables...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Answer was given by @DanGuzman and @Sepupic.

Mainly updating system object statistics helped improving the duration of the query as explained on this site: https://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-system-table-statistics-update/